# Multiple mappings in .htaccess files don't work

Tags: .htaccess, url, architecture

I have this mapping in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule outdoors/trees/(.*)/(.*) outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=$1
RewriteRule outdoors/parks/(.*)/(.*) outdoors/parks/park.php?tree_id=$1
```

For some reason the mapping to the trees works, but the one to the parks does not.
What I am trying to do is have a url like this:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=1

to redirect to one that looks like this:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/3/ParkName

Any idea why that isn't working with the redirects I showed above?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LAST` flag may work.

```
RewriteRule outdoors/trees/(.*)/(.*) outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule outdoors/parks/(.*)/(.*) outdoors/parks/park.php?tree_id=$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** Typo in `park_id`

```
RewriteRule outdoors/trees/(.*)/(.*) outdoors/trees/tree.php?tree_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule outdoors/parks/(.*)/(.*) outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now.  What does it do? :)

Comment: It is true, there was a typo, but it didn't fix the problem still :(